# Can no longer use CTRL+Left/Right in Bash Terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I usually use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to navigate between words on the command-line. I switched my laptop on this morning and can no longer do that. Instead, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> input code gets printed in the terminal.

Ie: Here's my output when I try to navigate with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>:

```
~ $ test test ;5D;5D;5D
```

Curiously, I can still use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> just fine in VIM.

Comment: Mayne you put something in your bashrc to enable this? Because it doesn't work by default for me on Ubuntu 15.10...

Comment: Please post the output of `grep bind ~/.bashrc `. Are you sourcing other files in `~/.bashrc` (`grep source ~/.bashrc`)?

Comment: Just curious, but what is the output of `echo $0`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open `~/.inputrc` file and add the following lines:

```
# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
```

Close and reopen shell.Now you should be able to use those keys.

Reasons for this behavior ? Not quite certain. For some reason or the other your `bash` stopped reading `/etc/inputrc` file, but it should be reading the one in your home folder

Comment: I think this issue started for me when I created a ~/.inputrc file. Would that do it?

Comment: @wjandrea yep, I tested that just now.  Prior to having blank  `~/.inputrc` the bash worked fine, started showing same control characters for output once blank `~/.inputrc` was created.   Removed it  - Ctrl+arrow keys work again.  `strace` reveals that if `.inputrc` exists, `bash`  won't read `/etc/inputrc`.  I'll mess around with this a bit more and update my answer

Comment: If you add `$include /etc/inputrc` to the top of your `~/.inputrc` file, then you can include the system-wide behavior and then extend that.

Answer (score 3):

Posting this an answer for visibility, as it's better than the current answer - however the real author is @corygross who wrote it as a comment above.

**Cause** when you have a `~/.inputrc` Ubuntu doesn't source the global `/etc/inputrc`

**Solution**: manually source `/etc/inputrc` in your personal `~/.inputrc`

```
set completion-ignore-case On

$include /etc/inputrc
```

This is much better than re-adding all the individual bits of Ubuntu's defaults back to your personal `/etc/inputrc`.